# Setting Java Runtime setting for all users on a client PC

Tags: java, console

We have a problem with a java application running out of memory. Our (Windows XP) client PCs have JRE 1.6 version 18 installed. I want to increase the -Xmx runtime parameter for the JRE to 512M but I can't seem to set this for all users. When I log in to the PC as Administrator and set the Runtime parameters in the Java Console, these settings only appear for my login.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you can try modifying a [System Deployment Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/properties.html) file?  Short version of usage below:

1. You need to create a file named `deployment.config` and put it in either `%SystemRoot%\Sun\Java\Deployment` or your JRE's `\lib\` directory.
2. The `deployment.config` contains a pointer to a `deployment.properties` file, as below:

   `deployment.system.config=file\:C\:/Windows/Sun/Java/Deployment/deployment.properties`
3. The `deployment.properties` file contains the properties that you want to set system-wide, one per line.  For my organization, we occasionally have problems with the JRE's caching causing problems, so I disable it with `deployment.cache.enabled=false` and prevent users from changing the value with `deployment.cache.enabled.locked=`  If you're not sure about the syntax, make the changes for yourself and look at the `deployment.properties` file normally located in `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment`.  At least, I think that's the path in XP.  On my Win 7 system it's in `AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment`.

I don't know if you can set the JRE options like this, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks. I had been changing the `deployment.properties` file in `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment`. But this is a simple solution for _all_ users

Comment: For anyone implementing this, it's worth noting that setting this seems to override any user-specific settings

Comment: Also, since `deployment.config` uses an URL to point at the `.properties` file, it's possible to host the file on an intranet server and have clients retrieve the file via HTTP.  You still have to deploy the `.config` though.

Comment: Thanks again. For anyone else trying to do this, copy the `deployment.properties` file from your `Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment` folder into your  `%SystemRoot%\Sun\Java\Deployment` folder. Then add the following line: `deployment.javaws.jre.0.args=-Xms64m -Xmx512m`. The '0' corresponds to the JRE you want to set these parameters for. It may be different, i.e. 1,2 etc., it depends how many JREs you have installed. It will be clear from the other lines in the file which number JRE you want.

Comment: I think it's wrong to accept an answer that only provides solution for one platform. Even if the question it self asked for Windows, people from other systems might still read this in future. For them it's almost useless information.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable to store the runtime options that will be used by the JVM during startup.

As far as setting this across users is concerned, you could do this via a logon script or via the Windows registry.

**Edit:**

Given the presence of a Java applet, it would be worthwhile to investigate whether Java 6 Update 10 or higher versions of the Java runtime could be installed on desktop PCs. Additionally, one would also have to specify the desired Xmx value using the [java_arguments](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_deployment.html#JAVA_ARGUMENTS) parameter to the applet; this parameter was introduced in 6u10. This might not be so trivial in the case of Oracle Forms 10g, as it requires editing of the web page where the applet is loaded from, but is worth a try.

See the [related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102003/how-can-i-start-an-java-applet-with-more-memory) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried setting windows environment variables `JAVA_OPTIONS`, `_JAVA_OPTIONS` and `JAVA_OPTS`. None of them seem to be getting picked up by the JVM (I'm checking this by looking at the `javaplugin.vm.options` value when I hit 's' in the java console). I should mention that the Java application is actually an applet. Oracle Forms 10g.

Comment: Ah ok, applets work differently; I've edited the answer now.

Comment: Thanks Vineet, the jre is 6u18. The easiest solution seems to be the one offered by afrazier below. Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`. I completely wasted the weekend trying to get Processing to use Unicode characters (despite its claims that it already does) and none of the 30+ things I tried worked… until this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The Windows environmental variable is called `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`.

The `deployment.properties` file is the same as starting `System Properties` -> `Java` -> (Tab) `Java` -> (Button) `View` and modifying the runtime parameter table entry.